# Vagrant port forwarding not working on w8

Tags: port, forwarding, vagrant

I've been trying all day and can't seem to get port forwarding on my Vagrant VM to work, I'm running a rails application using Thin as the web server and can successfully access the app from the IP 192.168.99.99:5000.

I need to use fonts from fonts.com which require I use a hostname like 'localhost' but when I use port forwarding in the vagrant file and try to boot the application Thin prompts an error such as can't use that port or do not have enough permissions.

This is the line I used in my vagrant file

```
config.vm.forward_port 8080, 5000
```

I'm hoping to access my rails application from

```
http://localhost:8080
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.
Also I'm running vagrant on windows 8.

Cheers

Comment: I also had this problem when working with a designer. Would love to now what you did.

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question, but in case anyone runs across the same issue, the newer format for the forwarded ports is:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
```

Ref: https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/forwarded_ports.html

Also, when running `vagrant up`, watch the log for any mention of the ports being forwarded. A successful case will look similar to the following:

```
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 4040 => 4040 (adapter 1)
    default: 7080 => 7080 (adapter 1)
    default: 7081 => 7081 (adapter 1)
    default: 8888 => 8888 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
```